# bootable usb not working not 2010 mac

Tags: mac, startup, iso

My macBook 2010 uni-book white never seems to find a bootable USB, but it finds a cloudready USB.

is it possible to change iso to BIN so chromebook recovery utility can use it. i did try dd but it does nothing. Is there any way to do this with cloudready OS.

edit: i use dd to make the usb bootable, like this
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb

on crosh, not linux on cloudready OS

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. Mac boot drives use neither iso nor bin files to boot from. You need to at least tell us what format your USB is & how you constructed it to make it bootable.

Comment: Mac won't boot from ext4 without a good deal of extra work - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/525845/how-to-boot-ubuntu-on-a-mac-from-external-usb-storage BTW, I very much doubt any repair utility designed for a chromebook is going to be much use to you. It won't be able to read HFS.

Comment: then how could cloudready boot if it is ex4. It is booted right now

Comment: Then that was made correctly. You're not giving us any more information to work from.